# Binding collections to angularjs to send multiple values for a property

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, entity-framework-4

I have been working with Angularjs with sometime along with .NET MVC 4.0 and Entity Framework.

Scenario:

We have got controllers and models and tables.

I have got a form that will be saving values to 3 tables, one to the table that is linked to model and controller by default. (ex: tablename: xyz, controller :xyzController.cs, Model: xyz.cs)

Now POSTing the data to table xyz is pretty easy, but to save data to say some different table say "abc" we are using an icollection. I collection because we are sending a collection of values for a particular property.

I am not able to:

1. Use angularjs to send multiple values for a property (Scenario is similar to **add more** options available. Ex: Projects (Can be multiple) )
2. Bind the angular component to the collection to save data to the table.

Thanx

Comment: You need to provide some more example for your 2 scenarios to make things clear.

Comment: I am sorry i wont be able to provide code due to some reasons. But the basic concept is, I want to first of all code in angularjs in such a way that on clicking on a button, a new dropdown list  (or any html control) gets added and in such a way we can send multiple values for that particular field.

Comment: And secondly, bind those values to icollection<> of a model. So it is like, if I am binding data using ng-model, then it would pass data to the property of the model class, but i need that data to be passed to the collection<> object (which is of some other model defined in this model due to database relations ). ng-model passes data to the object, but i need to pass it to the object of the object. So sort of a level deeper hierarchy.